# make description for a property

Tags: c#

How can I make a description for a property and receive it via system.reflection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [custom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx):

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Foo(Description = "Some description")]
    public string BarProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foos = (FooAttribute[])typeof(Bar)
            .GetProperty("BarProperty")
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FooAttribute), true);
        Console.WriteLine(foos[0].Description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an attribute for it:

```
System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute
```

although you can make yours if you want.